# SVN client is extremely slow on one server with many checkouts, but only for first touch

Tags: svn

## Setup

I have multiple boxes (all of the same size and specs). All of them except one have a single checkout of a remote repository (the same remote repository). However, one box has ~120 checkouts of that same remote repository.

## Problem

Doing a `svn status` on any of the boxes with a single checkout on it is instantaneous. (0.276s)

On the box I have ~120 checkouts of that same remote repository, doing a `svn status` takes a long time (29.398s)

## Funkiness

I just realized that if I do an `svn cleanup` on one of the slow checkouts and then a `svn status` that the status is then instantaneous. I further realized, actually, if I do an `svn status` and then another `svn status`, the first one is slow and the second one is fast.

## Thoughts

So I'm thinking it's some sort of caching issue. Any ides how to fix this?

## Reason

I'm using `svn status` as an example; however, my main issue is `svn switch` takes forever on these other checkouts which makes upgrading all of the checkouts an extremely long and tedious task.

Comment: Do you access the repository via HTTPS? Is the machine Windows-based?

Comment: I do access via HTTPS and no, it's not a windows machine. All the machines are Ubuntu running the same software.